# cant manage to move he layout to the right side

Tags: android, html, xml, imageview, textview

im working on an xml design , im trying to make the tvDate on the righ side , and the tvSender on the left , but for some reason they are being moved more left then they should, so the tvSender is out of the screen almost at all and the tvDate is not on on the right(is a bit little left then it should), what am i missing?? im really bad with xmls... also im trying to make the ivProfilePic a bit lower but i cant.
please help me with that... thank you very much!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="337dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="306dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSender"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="54dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textSize="10dp"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentWithBackground"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvMessage"
            android:background="@drawable/in_message_bg"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="right">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"/>


        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivProfilePic"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_36dp"/>

</LinearLayout></LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where does 337dp come from? why not using layout wight instead?

Comment: There are also other problems. How should `contentWithBackground`  place to right of its child?! and also `layout_toRightOf` works only in relative layout not in `LinearLayout`.